# Resultados Divergentes ao Filtrar Resposta em API

Tags: php, html, jquery, json

**Edit:** Consegui fazer com que ele criasse um único tab-pane, mas agora ele não está filtrando os jogos de acordo com o campeonato como podem ver na imagem abaixo, está imprimindo todos! Editei o código...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho um site em Wordpress e nele estou consumindo um Web Service, criei uma função para filtrar os campeonatos com base em algumas informações: 


**Sexo : M** 

**Modalidade : 2** 

**Categoria : 4**

Se todas forem **verdadeiras**, ele retorna o nome do respectivo **campeonato** e imprime na tela dentro de uma **`<div>` data-toggle** do bootstrap.

Dentro desse toggle, outra função compara os valores abaixo em duas URLs diferentes.

**$api_resultados['campeonato]**

**$api_campeonatos['codigo']**

Se estes valores forem **iguais**, ele imprime os jogos do campeonato com as informações abaixo:

**Mandante** x **Visitante**

A função funciona, o grande problema é que, ele não está puxando somente as informações dos campeonatos que foram comparados acima, e sim de todos eles, e na `<div>` de conteúdo **"tab-pane"** ele está criando uma para cada jogo, mas o correto seria que ele criasse apenas **um** tab pane com o **id do campeonato,** e **todos** os jogos com esse id fossem inseridos em formato de tabela dentro dela.

eu tentei usar o foreach depois da abertura da div e também um array_push, mas como é minha primeira vez com consumo de Web Service não estou tendo sucesso, alguém poderia me ajudar?

*Retorna os valores* e compara **SEXO, MODALIDADE E CATEGORIA:**

```
<?php 
    $api_campeonatos = 'https://sportsmanager.com.br/api/campeonatos?email=circuitoescolar@circuitoescolar.com.br&token=SXLSO8342HSDE78623GVS7234GNMSKL&ano=2018&status=A';
    $campeonatos = wp_remote_get( $api_campeonatos );
    $campeonatos_data = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $campeonatos ), true );
    $retorno_campeonatos = array(); // <- mudar para array

    if($campeonatos_data){
        foreach($campeonatos_data as $row){
            if(!is_array($row)){
                //$retorno = $retorno.'<td>'.$row.'</td>';
            }else{
                if($row['sexo'] == 'M' && $row['modalidade'] == 2 && $row['categoria'] == 4){
                    $retorno_campeonatos[] = array('valor' => '<td>'.$row['nome'].'</td>', 'id' => $row['codigo']); // <--- adiciona
                }   
            }   
        }
    }
?>
```

**Imprime o nome do campeonato em um list-group:**

```
<script>

$(function(){

    var html = '';

    var html2 = '';

    <?php foreach($retorno_campeonatos as $valor){ ?>

        html += '<a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="list" href="#bloco-<?php echo $valor['id'];?>" role="tab"><?php echo $valor['valor'];?></a>';

        html2 += '<div class="tab-pane" id="bloco-<?php echo $valor['id'];?>" role="tabpanel"><div id="cont-<?php echo $valor['id'];?>"></div></div>';

    <?php } ?>

    $('#myList').html(html);

    $('#tabList').html(html2);

});

</script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">   
        <div id="contents">
            <div class="list-group" id="myList" role="tablist">
            </div>

            <div id="tabList" class="tab-content">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Compara os valores **$api_resultados['campeonato] : $api_campeonatos['codigo']** em duas URLs diferentes e retorna os jogos dos campeonatos:

```
<?php
// pega os valores da primeira URL
$api_campeonatos = 'https://sportsmanager.com.br/api/campeonatos?email=circuitoescolar@circuitoescolar.com.br&token=SXLSO8342HSDE78623GVS7234GNMSKL&ano=2018&status=A';
$campeonato = wp_remote_get( $api_campeonatos );
$campeonato = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $campeonato ), true );

// pega os valores da segunda URL
$api_resultados = 'https://sportsmanager.com.br/api/resultados?email=circuitoescolar@circuitoescolar.com.br&token=SXLSO8342HSDE78623GVS7234GNMSKL&ano=2018&status=A';
$resultado = wp_remote_get( $api_resultados );
$resultado = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $resultado ), true );

$retorno_resultados = array();

foreach($campeonato as $camp){
    foreach($resultado as $result){
        if(isset($camp['codigo']) && isset($result['campeonato']) && $camp['codigo'] == $result['campeonato']){
            $retorno_resultados[] = array(
                'mandante' => '<td>'.$result['mandante'].'</td>', 
                'visitante' => '<td>'.$result['visitante'].'</td>', 
                'id' => $camp['codigo'],
                'data' => '<td>'.$camp['data'],
                'placar1n' => '<td>'.$result['placar1n'].'</td>',
                'placar2n' => '<td>'.$result['placar2n'].'</td>',
                'placar1p' => '<td>'.$result['placar1p'].'</td>',
                'placar2p' => '<td>'.$result['placar2p'].'</td>',
                'placar1s' => '<td>'.$result['placar1s'].'</td>',
                'placar2s' => '<td>'.$result['placar2s'].'</td>'
            ); // <--- adiciona
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**Imprime os valores dos jogos dentro de uma `<div>` de conteúdo tab-pane:**

```
<script>

$(function(){

    var html3 = '';

    <?php foreach($retorno_resultados as $val){ ?>

    html3 += '<td id="<?php echo $val['id'];?>"><?php echo $val['mandante'];?>x<?php echo $val['visitante'];?></td>';

    <?php } ?>

    <?php foreach($retorno_resultados as $id_camp){ ?>
    $('#cont-<?php echo $id_camp['id'];?>').html(html3);
    <?php } ?>
});

</script>
```

**Retorno JSON URL:campeonatos:**

```
 {
"codigo": "19",
"nome": "CIRCUITO ESCOLAR - SÉRIE OURO",
"modalidade": "2",
"categoria": "4",
"sexo": "M",
"data": "2018-08-13 00:00:00",
"atualizacao": null,
"status": "N"
},
  {
"codigo": "18",
"nome": "CIRCUITO ESCOLAR - SÉRIE PRATA",
"modalidade": "2",
"categoria": "4",
"sexo": "M",
"data": "2018-08-13 00:00:00",
"atualizacao": null,
"status": "N"
},
  {
"codigo": "36",
"nome": "CIRCUITO ESCOLAR - SÉRIE PRATA",
"modalidade": "2",
"categoria": "8",
"sexo": "F",
"data": "2018-08-13 00:00:00",
"atualizacao": null,
"status": "N"
},
  {
"codigo": "20",
"nome": "CIRCUITO ESCOLAR - SÉRIE PRATA",
"modalidade": "2",
"categoria": "6",
"sexo": "M",
"data": "2018-08-13 00:00:00",
"atualizacao": null,
"status": "N"
},
```

**Retorno JSON URL:resultados:**

```
{
"codigo": "31",
"campeonato": "18",
"data": "2018-09-11 00:00:00",
"horario": "19H",
"local": "2",
"realizada": "N",
"jogo": "0",
"fase": "2",
"rodada": "0",
"mandante": "5",
"visitante": "3",
"placar1n": null,
"placar2n": null,
"placar1p": null,
"placar2p": null,
"placar1s": null,
"placar2s": null,
"grupo1": "",
"grupo2": "",
"quadra": "2",
"obs": null
},
  {
"codigo": "32",
"campeonato": "18",
"data": "2018-09-25 00:00:00",
"horario": "19H",
"local": "4",
"realizada": "N",
"jogo": "0",
"fase": "2",
"rodada": "0",
"mandante": "7",
"visitante": "3",
"placar1n": null,
"placar2n": null,
"placar1p": null,
"placar2p": null,
"placar1s": null,
"placar2s": null,
"grupo1": "",
"grupo2": "",
"quadra": "4",
"obs": null
},
  {
"codigo": "25",
"campeonato": "19",
"data": "2018-08-13 00:00:00",
"horario": "19h",
"local": "9",
"realizada": "N",
"jogo": "0",
"fase": "2",
"rodada": "0",
"mandante": "2",
"visitante": "6",
"placar1n": null,
"placar2n": null,
"placar1p": null,
"placar2p": null,
"placar1s": null,
"placar2s": null,
"grupo1": "",
"grupo2": "",
"quadra": "9",
"obs": null
},
```

**OBS: EXISTEM MAIS REGISTROS NO RETORNO.**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual é exatamente a sua dúvida?

Comment: a minha dúvida é, como eu posso imprimir todos os retornos da URL resultados com a comparação desses valores _$camp['codigo']) && isset($result['campeonato']_ em urls diferentes, dentro do tab-pane, não criar um tab pane por registro, que no caso é o que está acontecendo.

Comment: http://circuitoescolar.com.br/new/teste/ essa url é onde eu estou efetuando os testes.

Comment: adicionei uma imagem do que está acontecendo no final da pergunta, como pode ver, o script está criando um **"tab-pane"** para cada jogo que tenha o valor **"campeonato":"18"**, eu preciso que ele crie apenas _um_ tab-pane, com todos os jogos que tenham o valor **"campeonato":"18"** dentro, em formato de tabela.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo consegui exibir somente um tab-pane, mas o retorno das informações está errado, você não poderia me explicar por favor?